# Cannot connect to MS SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a client who use MSSql 11 as database. I spent days trying to figure out how let php work with MSSQL and go over direction but still not work.

1. My system is Windows 7  x86
2. I have downloaded WampServer Version 2.2 which has Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13, then SQLSRV2.0 and saved the file in "`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext`"
3. Then I added the two line to php.ini :

   ```
   extension_dir="C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext"
   extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
   ```
4. Then I called phpinfo() function but it does not load SQLSRV
5. Last I tried to this code. It returns the following error :

   ```
   Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect before.
   ```

But after I downloaded different version of WAMP, it shows nothing now. I really need this to work, please help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

 <?php
   $serverName = "my sever name";

   $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"test","UID"=> "my id","PDW" => "password" );

   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);

       if( $conn === false )

          die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: check if u need Thread safe version , I am using extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll in my php.ini . Check in phpinfo in the first section if your apache is running in thread safe just check in phpinfo if Thread Safety: enabled

Comment: Hmm, even know after adding the code indentation, it fails to show?

Comment: Thanks there is  Compiler MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) and Thread Safety enabled  in my PHPINFO. So i may need php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll. i will try it now

Comment: my extenstion php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll is checked, But still did now show in phpinfo page. what else i am missing. Actually, i check every possibility

Comment: Good news. I uninstall the old WAMP and install WampServer Version 2.4. and click php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll. Now sqlsrv is show my PHPINFO. Now move to second step, test the php code. GOOD LUCK TO ME